# How do I make large text boxes use null instead of blank string when empty

Tags: forms, ms-access, textbox, null

Here is my issue. I am currently forced to use Access and I am writing some generic validation that I can add to forms.

It was all going well and catching empty fields in form_error based on the error "You tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Varient data type"

All of my required varchar fields are NOT NULL.

Unfortunately if a textbox has a control source to a large varchar DB field it behaves differently. I can't remember the size threshold but assume this behaviour difference would be equivalent to text vs. memo in an access table).

Basically, if you delete the contents of a small text box control it attempts to write null and the error is caught. All good.

If you do the same on a text box linked to a larger varchar, or memo database field then it writes a blank string which is considered valid.

I have confirmed this by changing the db Schema between varchar(50) and varchar(256), updating the linked table in Access and restarting Access for good measure.

I am hoping someone can point me to a property to set or some tiny piece of generic code that can be added to make all text boxes behave the same regarding writing NULL/Empty string when they are empty regardless of the size of the DB field they are connected to.

Just to note that also the box behaves differently on insert or edit. If not filled on insert it does leave the DB entry as null.

Comment: Just to note..
I can resolve this by adding the code:

`Private Sub MyTextControl_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.MyTextControl = "" Then
        Me.MyTextControl = Null
    End If
End Sub`

I just don't want to have to hunt down all the text controls linked to large varchars and add this code just to get the generic form error checking to work. It kind of defeats the object of it being generic.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much the way you have to do it. You could set up a "Validation Rule" on each text field, but again that would require hunting down all the text controls.

You can make that job easier. If you check the Object Dependencies of the tables, you can get a list of all the forms (and queries, etc.) involved. Then you can be sure you have hit each one.